# Unexpected ParseFloat result

Tags: javascript

Today, I have seen strange issue with `parseFloat` in Javascript. When I an doing addition operation of the value I have seen some strange values, below are the examples:

```
parseFloat("31.099")+1;
```

Output:

```
32.099000000000004
```

Why do I have only problem with 31.099?

Answer (score 0):

Floating numbers are always strange. Check out some descriptions in [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php) as well. There is a warning about precision.

Comment: If you look at their binary representation, there's nothing strange about them.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the programming languages do this, when you add an int to a floating number, it will make an approximation of the result. One work around would be to create your floating type and separate the floating value from the integer value.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, floating point numbers are not always precise. It's because fractions cannot be precisely represented in binary.

To fix it, use toFixed() to round floating point numbers to the amount of precision you want. For example, for two decimal places:

```
num.toFixed(2)
```

Comment: Hi Kieran, thank you for your reply. But i am not sure fixed size of precision , In that how should i approach with toFixed(2)